# IRkernel for Jupyter

Tags: r, linux, jupyter-notebook, devtools

Trying to setup R-kernel for jupyter, however I get the following error,
I am following the instructions on https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel,
However, it fails on install.packages("devtools") .

```
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for the version of libcurl... 7.19.7
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
checking for struct stat.st_mtim... no
checking for struct stat.st_mtimespec... no
checking for struct stat.st_mtime_nsec... no
checking for futimens... no
checking for qsort_r... no
checking for qsort_s... no

  ----- Results of the git2r package configure -----

OpenSSL to talk over HTTPS...........: yes
LibSSH2 to enable the SSH transport..: no

  --------------------------------------------------

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -Ilibgit2/src -Ilibgit2/include -Ilibgit2/deps/http-parser     -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/include -DGIT_ARCH_64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DGIT_OPENSSL -DLIBGIT2_NO_FEATURES_H -DGIT_SHA1_OPENSSL -DGIT_USE_NSEC   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/include   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/include  -c git2r.c -o git2r.o
make: /home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: Command not found
make: *** [git2r.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/lib/R/library/git2r’
ERROR: dependency ‘git2r’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/sheetal/software/anaconda3/lib/R/library/devtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJ1BaT2/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools") :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try updating [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (7.58.0 is current) and/or installing [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/)

Comment: How to update libcurl? I installed libssh2

Comment: Probably your package manager, if you're on linux

Comment: I ran , curl --version. It gives the output,
curl 7.55.1 (x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.55.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2n zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0. It shows libcurl version 7.55.1

Comment: So will `git2r` install now?

Comment: No it doesn't install

Comment: So what error message is it giving now? If it all looks the same, the libraries aren't installed in locations on $PATH.

Comment: @alistaire thats right. the $PATH was not correctly specified

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best way to install IRkernel is to use anaconda.
In my mac (I guess is the same on Linux and Windows) I typed:

```
conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

Then I started started R typing:

```
R
```

Finally, I have install the kernelspec to tell Jupyter about IRkernel, with the option user=FALSE for installation in the global environment:

```
IRkernel::installspec(user=FALSE)
```

Hope it helps!